# How to set up a webbrowser DocumentCompleted Eventhandler in F#

Tags: winforms, f#, webbrowser-control

I am trying something as simple as connecting to a webpage with the `Webbrowser` property and printing the html body tag to the console. Though apparently a so called [DocumentCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) Event handler is needed.

I have been trying for hours now to convert one of the thousands C# examples out there into F#.

```
[<STAThread>]
do
let webbrowser1 = new WebBrowser()
webbrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.google.dk/"))
webbrowser1.DocumentCompleted <- new 
WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(printfn "%A" 
webbrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText)
```

Now I have to call SOS since im not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

The following snippet ran successfully in LINQPad. The System.Windows.Forms assembly had to be referenced.

```
let webbrowser1 = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser()
webbrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.google.dk/"))
webbrowser1.DocumentCompleted.Add (fun _ ->
    printfn "%A" webbrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText)
```

Comment: Have you tried this? This returns nothing in my end. It compiles but sure does not print the body tag of google.com

Comment: I got the whole Google front page.

Comment: Complete source posted.

Comment: I just copy pasted your entire code. Still a linebreak is all that is being written to the console. If this is your complete code and your are not using [<STAThread>]
do. how do you set a single threading apartment then? i get an exception if i run your code without setting STAThreading somehow.

Comment: I wonder why there is a "do" after a "STAThread" in your source. I suspect you run this stuff before the main function is called, and this is possibly too early. I've seen that before. Try instead to run this from your main function, directly or indirectly.

Comment: there is no main function. Atm there is only your code which returns an exception if i dont set STAThreading. Else it returns a linebreak to the console.

Comment: I get an exception referring to STAThread when I try to run this in a console application. Not sure what to do about it, but I have a better suggestion, possibly. Follow the link: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/fvsc-download/

Comment: I know of the WebRequest class to obtain this. Though my intent is not use this on google but on a web with login functions and webbrowser have some nice features to achieve this. Thanks  for your help though